# searching for strings in array of character/strings matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have the following array:-

```
dir=['E','B','R']
```

I want to find the index of the elemen 'E'.

```
>> find(dir=='E')

ans =

     1
```

But i want to do the same for an array of strings rather than array of characters like:

```
dir=['E','G','T','BR']
```

But there is an error to find 'BR'. I want the output to be 4.

```
>> find(dir=='BR')
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

How to work-around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you look at the documentation on string (char array) handling in matlab such as [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html?refresh=true).

What you want  to do is work with cell arrays of strings:

```
 dir = {'E','G','T','BR'}
 find(ismember(dir,'BR'))

 ans = 4
```